# Alternating Reciprocal of Squares

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know that the infinite sum of the reciprocals of squares converges to $\pi^2/6$. Interested by this, I looked at a different sum. It is similar to the previously mentioned series, but it alternates signs: $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{i^2}$. I tried adding up the first several terms but I could not identify any interesting convergence (up to $\ n=14$ the sum is 0.82009731292). Is it possible that the series does not converge?

Thanks.

Comment: The sum expression was wrong, so I corrected it. The alternating series converges, since the series converges absolutely. Not sure if this question will be well received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks, Igor. I think I figured it out. You take the original sum which converges to $\pi^2/6$. The even part is a half squared plus a fourth squared plus a sixth squared, etc. Factoring out a fourth shows that this even part sum is one fourth of the total sum. So, the odd part is 3/4 of the sum. 3/4 - 1/4 is a half, so the series converges to $\pi^2/12$.

Again, thanks.

Comment: You should mark this answer as the solution. Thanks for explaining :)

Answer (score 4):

Mathematica says the sum is $\pi^2/12,$ and this is not not hard to prove - break the sum into the even and the odd parts, and transform into the sum of reciprocal squares.