# Solving for a term in a summation

Tags: summation

How can you solve for the summation term, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(n\pi)^2}$, in the Fourier series below?

$$
x^2 \thicksim \frac{1}{3} + 4\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(n\pi)^2}\cos{n\pi x}
$$

After rearranging the terms, I'm stuck at dividing out the cosine term from the summation.

$$
\frac{x^2}{4} - \frac{1}{12} \thicksim  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(n\pi)^2}\cos{n\pi x}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try plugging in $x=0$ to the original expression. Recall, $\cos(0)=1$.

Comment: Duh!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Factor out the $$\frac {-1}{\pi^2}$$

To turn the question into $$\frac {-1}{\pi^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2}$$

Using [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1292251/alternating-reciprocal-of-squares) we have $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2}=\frac {\pi^2}{12}$$

Hence the answer is $\frac {-1}{12}$

Answer (score 1):

First, note that $\sum1/n^{2}$ is convergent. Therefore, 
$$
\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^{2}}=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{(2n)^{2}}-\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^{2}}=\frac{1}{4}\left(\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n^{2}}-\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{1}{(n+1/2)^{2}}\right)=\frac{1}{4}\left(\zeta(2)-\zeta(2,1/2)\right).
$$
$\zeta(2)=\pi^{2}/6$ is the solution of the [Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem).
As for the second term, you can use [a well-known identity regarding the Hurwitz zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function#Relation_to_Dirichlet_L-functions) to get $\zeta(2,1/2)=(4-1)\zeta(2)=\pi^{2}/2$.
Therefore,
$$
\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^{2}}=-\frac{\pi^{2}}{12}.
$$
Divide by $\pi^2$ to get $-1/12$.